# I want to build a connector to choose file Html in location and process it

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

In AnypointStudio, I want to build a connector for open html Login file.
As img
[Example mule open html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJn4L.png)

Please help me. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

//Please try below code -
//login.html is kept at src/main/resources

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8089" basePath="/loginpage" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="GetLoginPageFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <parse-template location="login.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
</flow>
```